# TimeOut Issue in Oracle Bpel 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, soa, bpel

Getting Timeout issue in bpel faulted instances on Oracle SOA Suite 11g. Please find error:
weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException:Transaction timed out after 300 seconds.

To further explain, I am having read adapter reading a file having 5000 records, and db transaction taking more than 5 minutes to put in database resulting in JTA transaction timeout, hence rollback. Is there any change I can make in weblogic datasource configuration or soa infra configuration to rectify this.

In simple language, Bpel process calling a db adapter taking longer time , hence timeout. I hope this explains all.

Comment: You should be a little more specific.

Comment: I'd say you should be _a lot_ more specific :) Any code for instance?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this.

Changed following timeout settings in weblogic console:

1. Set timeouts in the soa EJB’s: Open the Weblogic console and click in the navigation menu on the left on “Deployments”. Expand “soa-infra” by clicking on [+] and expand node “EJBs” in the same way. Increase the “Transaction Timeout” (value in seconds) to 3600 in the “Configuration” tab for the following EJB’s by clicking on them:
       BPELEngineBean
       BPELDeliveryBean
       BPELActivityManagerBean
       BPELServerManagerBean
       BPELProcessManagerBean
       BPELInstanceManagerBean
       BPELFinderBean
2. In the Domain Structure, select Services > JTA, Increase the JTA transaction timeout value to  3600.

References: 
http://technology.amis.nl/2011/11/18/timeouts-in-oracle-soa-suite-11g/
http://www.albinsblog.com/2012/05/weblogictransactioninternaltimedoutexce.html#.UYuFT7Wmh1Y

Answer (score 0):

I propose to focus on the DB performance issue.
For 99.9 % of the performance issues, bad DB or query design is the reason.

Try to use adequate indexes and queries which allow the DB to make use of the indexes.
Furthermore try to understand the DB optimizer.

Precondition: You are able to write the SQL statement by your own, not bound to a framework which creates inefficient SQL and tricks the DB optimizer. I've seen bad frameworks quite too often...

Only if you have a really huge amount of data (billions of rows) with low selectivity and huge joins with other huge tables, or complex recursion, it will get difficult.

=> Always search for the root cause of the problem. You will learn a lot and be a lot more professional. ;)